# Making animation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, animation, mmqgis, timemanager, animatedmarker

I wanted to create an animation video in QGIS. I had tried the Time Manager and MMQGIS plugins. But I was not possible.

The animation should goes like this:

Suppose I have 4 points location points saved in a vector file and having some other attributes values of that point.

Then I want the animation to start from 1st point and hovering there for 5 seconds and displaying the attribute value of that point next it should move to 2nd point slowly and while doing so I should make a tail line and when it comes to point B it should stop there and then wait for 5 sec and so on till the final point.

So the whole process can be broken into 7 parts:

1st part:  showing attribute values of point A for 5 sec

2nd part: moving from point A to point B and leaving tail line as it moves

3rd part: showing attribute values of point B for 5 sec

4th part: moving from point B to point C and leaving tail line as it moves

5th part: showing attribute values of point C for 5 sec

6th part: moving from point C to point D and leaving tail line as it moves

7th part: showing attribute values of point D for 5 sec

Comment: Please describe what you have tried so far and where you got stuck. This should be possible with the tools you mentioned but without knowing what you already tried, it's hard to say where things went wrong.

Comment: Till now i had managed to make the point move through different points but it does not a rail line as it moves and it does not pause at the location to show the attributes value

Comment: Duplicate the points at the locations where a stop should occur and make sure to add time stamps that are 5 sec apart.